# Interval of Convergence for a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

What can one say about the interval of convergence of the series solution, centered at $x_0=0$, of: 
$$(x^2+2)y'' + \dfrac {x^2+1}{x-2}y' + \dfrac {2x^2-1}{x^2+1}y=0$$

I'm mainly looking to know if there is an easy way to look at this function and determine the interval of convergence without going through the complete solving method with series.

Any tips and tricks are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide by $x^2+2$ you can write this as a first order linear system with non constant coefficients. In particular, you have existence and uniqueness as long as the coefficients are defined, so in $(-\infty,2)$.

Comment: The question is about the convergence radius of the series solution at $x_0=0$.

Comment: Yes but since there is uniqueness I suspect the power series will be the unique solution

Comment: But the power series might only have a finite radius of convergence.

Comment: agree, so the radius of convergence should be $2$ but I don't have a valid proof.